# React native - call function to close modal from another component gives `undefined is not an object`

Tags: javascript, react-native, modal-dialog

I am trying to call function of parent class from child to close modal. However, I always get `undefined is not an object this.ref.modal`

This is what I have:

```
1st 

Import Two from ‘./Two’;


export default class One extends Component {
    static closeModal(){
            this.refs.modal.close();
    }
    <Modal>
    </Two>
    </Modal>
}

2nd

Import One from ‘./One’;

export default class Two extends Component {
    randomFunction(){
       One.CloseModal();
}
}
```

First component is a modalbox and second component is Camera. I would like to close first modal from Camera component. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to do is have a parent component, One, pass a function to the child, Two, and have the child component call the function. The general way you should approach passing information, whether it be data or functions, from a parent to the child is through props. This could be achieved through the following approach:

**One.js**

```
import Two from ‘./Two’;

export default class One extends Component {
    closeModal(){
        this.refs.modal.close();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Modal>
                <Two closeModal={this.closeModal} />
            </Modal
        )
    }
}
```

**Two.js**

```
export default class Two extends Component {
    randomFunction() {
        this.props.closeModal()
    }
}
```

The key part is in One.js when I instantiate the Two component and pass in the closeModal function as a prop. Then, in Two.js you can access all props passed into the class within the "this.props" object.

Notice how I didn't have to import One.js in Two.js. This is because in React you should think of each component as its own entity that doesn't know anything about the parent class that is using it. Two.js just knows that it's parent will be using it and passing in a "closeModal" function as a prop which it can use.

You can read more about props and look at examples [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props.html). To read more about thinking hierarchically with react, you can look at [this guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Before using *this.ref.modal* you must set your ref like `ref='modal'`. And you also need to bind your function *closeModal* before passing it as a prop.

**One.js**

```
import Two from './Two'

export default class One extends Component {
    closeModal(){
        this.refs.modal.close();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal ref='modal'>
                <Two closeModal={() => this.closeModal()} />
            </Modal
        )
    }
}
```

**Two.js**

```
export default class Two extends Component {
    randomFunction() {
        this.props.closeModal()
    }
}
```

For more information refer to 
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html and
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html